# Why does PowerShell cut off column values?

Tags: powershell

When I use autosize it only fixes the last column and then it breaks the first column, meaning all the values shows up for the last with a halfway chopped off value for the first column. Is there a fix for that?

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://contoso.intranet.com -Limit All | where {$_.RootWeb.Created -ge $Yesterday -And $_.RootWeb.Created -lt $Tomorrow} | ft Url, @{Name='Created';Expression={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Format-Table -Autosize` is limited to the width of your screen buffer. One option would be to output it to a text file or use `Out-GridView` rather than `Format-Table`

e.g.

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://contoso.intranet.com -Limit All 
| where {$_.RootWeb.Created -ge $Yesterday -And $_.RootWeb.Created -lt $Tomorrow} 
| ft Url, @{Name='Created';Expression={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} 
| Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
| Out-String -Width 4096 `
| Out-File C:\SPSites.txt
```

or

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://contoso.intranet.com -Limit All 
| where {$_.RootWeb.Created -ge $Yesterday -And $_.RootWeb.Created -lt $Tomorrow} 
| ft Url, @{Name='Created';Expression={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}} 
| Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 18):

This gives the kind of output you would probably expect:

```
[command] | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 10000 #| clip.exe
```

For example, try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "." | Select-Object * | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 10000 #| clip.exe
```

`Format-Table -AutoSize` fits to the expected output size, or the size of the elements, *whichever is smaller*. Since your output is probably less than 10,000 characters wide this command should fit to whatever your data is.

NOTE: `clip.exe` is a built in Windows command that lets you pipe onto the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 3000
$newsize.width = 3000
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
```

Add this to the top of your script, fixes length issues :) its a total hack but works :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the output of `format-table` to another `format-table` which may be causing the problems. Try replacing the first with a `select-object`, the command should look exactly the same otherwise:

```
select-object Url, @{Name='Created';Expression={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{label="Size in MB";Expression={$_.usage.storage/1MB}}
```

Comment: Or just put the -AutoSize -Wrap parameters on the first Format-Table and get rid of the second Format-Table altogether.

Comment: @keith oh yeah (slapping hand to forehead)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of **-AutoSize**. It's defeating the purpose of **-Wrap**. I also agree with zdan and Keith Hill that there's no reason to pipe one **Format-Table** into another and that you should just add the switches to the first instance.

So, try this:

```
Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://contoso.intranet.com -Limit All | ?{$_.RootWeb.Created -ge $Yesterday -And $_.RootWeb.Created -lt $Tomorrow} | ft -Wrap Url, @{n='Created';e={$_.RootWeb.Created}},@{n="Size in MB";e={$_.usage.storage/1MB}}
```

(I abbreviated some things to reduce the scrolling. Also, AFAIK "Name" and "Label" are interchangeable in **ft** format specs; just pointing that out because I noticed that you used one of each.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it's a total hack, but together with `ft -autosize` it does the job I was looking for perfectly.

(...)

```
$list2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | Sort-Object -Property FileName | format-table -autosize > $filePath\dir.txt
```

(...)

Answer (score 0):

The info **Syed** provided does help (increasing the screen buffer width). However, if you use `-AutoSize`, the last column might still get truncated.
To solve that issue, you would need to explicitly set the width you'd like for that column. It might not look pretty, but it works. For example:

```
#:: ft = Format-Table, n = name, e = expression, a = alignment
$pshost = get-host
$pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
$newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
$newsize.height = 3000
$newsize.width = 3000
$pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
    
Get-AppxPackage | sort name | ft @{n='Name';e={$_.Name};a='left';width=44}, @{n='Version';e={$_.Version};a='left';width=20},@{n='InstallLocation';e={$_.InstallLocation};a='left';width=105} >D:\Installed_AppX_Packages.txt
```

In the above command, I'm outputting a list of installed AppX packages to a file. I've explicitly set each column to a certain width. Without doing so, the last column (InstallLocation) has some values cut-off. So I checked which value was the longest, and set the width accordingly.

Comment: I've found a simpler option: